# Retry on Failure for Async calls Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I am running a batch(10000 size) process after reading data from using asynchronous queries.

```
future_list = []
for key in batch:
    query = SimpleStatement("select * from mytable where pk = %s")
    future_obj = cass_session.execute_sync(query, (key,))
    future_list.append(future_obj)

result_list = []
for future_obj in future_list:
    result = future_obj.result()
    result_list.append(result)
```

Once I have my results I need to process them together. But I am experiencing timeouts even after setting cass_session.timeout = 60.

How do I handle the timeout exceptions and retry the query so that I will not miss out on any data?

P.S - I read about error callback but it will just return me only the exception, not the statement which failed

Comment: mark query as idempotent, then it will be retried automatically

Comment: @AlexOtt Yeah, I think setting my statement to idempotent might solve the issue. Will it try infinitely though till it gets results? I might need results at some point and if there is a genuine problem I don't want the program to get stuck at future_obj.result().
I can't find it in the documentation to set a limit on number of retries - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/idempotence/

Comment: It depends on the driver, out of head (maybe I'm wrong), Java driver should retry once only